# Mamp-PRO 6.x on Mac Catalina can't access the folder with my websites anymore

Tags: macos-catalina, mamp-pro

I upgraded from Mamp-PRO 5 to 6 and now all the websites are red.

In the «document root» field, it says «restricted folder» and when I try to add a new host, I can't select a folder - they're all greyed out.

My files are located in /myUser/Library/Webserver/Documents/…

I gave apachectl, httpd and Mamp-Pro full disk access in the system preferences.

Any idea if I can fix this without moving the whole folder to a different location?

The exisiting websites are working, though (e.g. I can start Apache and the local websites are responding).

(running MacOS Catalina)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that changing the name of htdocs to localhost will do the trick. However, here are the steps I took to correct the problem:

- Stopped MAMP Pro servers
- Copied Applications/MAMP/htdocs to my Dropbox folder (I'm guessing it could go in the documents folder or anywhere else)
- Clicked on *localhost* in MAMP and chose the new document root location (*Dropbox/htdocs* in my case)
- Chose new document roots for all my hosts at the new location

Of note, MAMP automatically changed the name of *htdocs* to *localhost*. This is the basis for my assertion at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem on Mojave, I filed a bug report to the developer and will respond if I receive something.

My files are located in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs and I cannot chose any folder within that folder.
Launching the (red marked) existing hosts works, interestingly. Just not editing nor creating new ones.

Comment: Did the developer reply?

Comment: @karl-letcher: Yes, sorry for the late response. The developer/author advised me to move all my folders / hosts *outdise* or the /MAMP/htdocs folder. I did not follow up immediately since I needed a working setup (and therefor downgraded back to 5), however I give it a try today and that worked flawlessly.

Actually there is a *small* textual hint during the upgrade to 6.x, stating that "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs can NOT be used as document root" - which I read over, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the same document root with multiple hostnames. This can be done via the "Aliases" option in the "General" section.

This answer comes a little late and is not the answer to the original question, but maybe this will help others to work around the limitation of MAMP PRO 6.

Unfortunately, I didn't get a tip in the right direction from MAMP PRO support or via a Google search.